# PHP Session doesn't get read in next page after login validation, Why?

Tags: session, location, session-variables, php, ob-start

### I have a web site and when my users login it takes them to

**verify.php**

(where it connects to the DataBase and matches email and password to the user                                           input and if OK puts client data into sessions and take the client to /memberarea/index.php ELSE back to login page with message "Invalid Email or password!")

```
<?php
  ob_start();
  session_start();

  $email=$_POST['email'];
  $pass=md5($_POST['pass']);

  include("conn.php"); // connects to Database
  $sql="SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE email='$email' AND pass='$pass'";
  $result=mysql_query($sql);

  $new=mysql_fetch_array($result);

  $_SESSION['fname']=$new['fname'];
  $_SESSION['lname']=$new['lname'];
  $_SESSION['email']=$new['email'];
  $_SESSION['passwrd']=$new['passwrd'];


  $no=mysql_num_rows($result);

   if ($no==1){
    header('Location:memberarea/index.php');
   }else {

        header("Location:login.php?m=$msg"); //msg="Invalid Login"
   }

  ?>
```

then after email id and password is verified it takes them to `

**/memberarea/index.php**

(This is where the problem happens.)

where in index.php it checks if a session has been created in-order to block hackers to enter member area and sends them back to the login page.

```
<?
 session_start(); 
 isset($_SESSION['email'])` && `isset($_SESSION['passwrd'])`
```

The problem is the client gets verified in verify.php (the code is above)

In varify.php only after I put 
`ob_start();` ontop of `session_start();` 
It moves on to `/memberarea/index.php` ,

If I remove `ob_start()` 
It keeps the client on the verify.php page and displays error **header is alredy SENT**.

after I put `ob_start()` it goes in to `/memberarea/index.php` but the session is blank,

so it goes back to the login page and displays the error ($msg) "Invalid Login" which I programed to display.

Can anyone tell me why the session cant pass values from verify.php to `/memberarea/index.php`

Comment: Make your question readable, someone will run away after looking at such a big para with no code,,

Comment: Anything in the error log? Also verify you aren't redirecting non-www to www or vice-versa.

Comment: @Mr.Alien If you'd look at the OP you'd find he is a new SO user thus probably has no idea how to format properly...It is upon us - the community, to format the questons properly...

Comment: Your question does not contain enough technical information like configuration and concrete code to be answered. You're basically inviting to guess here (not that this was intended by you, just saying). Please edit your question and add the code and your session configuration.

Comment: @shadyyx: No, you can guide the user, but you don't do the users work. That would actually prevent her/him from learning.

Comment: Can you post the relevant code instead? I read this a few times but I'm still not quite sure what you're describing. Just the first few lines of the files should do it, plus whatever function you use to set the session bits once authenticated. You're probably missing a `session_start()` somewhere, but it's very hard to say at this point.

Comment: Have you also written --session_start();-- at the top of /memberarea/index.php. It starts the session.

Comment: please check Anywhere you destroyed it
you can also pass values vie Cookies.

Comment: Realy sorry! Now check and see if you'll can understand my question.  Yes, I used session start at the top. Thanks

Comment: try to print the session variable after you assign them. are they printing?

Comment: @ganeshrj: yes I try'ed printing and it shows nothing!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that some white space is getting from *conn.php*. If the `?>` is at the end of *conn.php* , please remove it ( There may be some white space after it) and make sure that there is no white space before `<?` in *conn.php*. Then you won't get `header is alredy SENT` error.

And you should set the session data after making sure there is result as given below:

```
<?php
  ob_start();
  session_start();

  $email=$_POST['email'];
  $pass=md5($_POST['pass']);

  include("conn.php"); // connects to Database
  $sql="SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE email='$email' AND pass='$pass'";
  $result=mysql_query($sql);

  $no=mysql_num_rows($result);

   if ($no==1){

       // Set the session data here.
       $new=mysql_fetch_array($result);

       $_SESSION['fname']=$new['fname'];
       $_SESSION['lname']=$new['lname'];
       $_SESSION['email1']=$new['email1'];
       $_SESSION['passwrd']=$new['passwrd'];

       header('Location:memberarea/index.php');
   }
   else {

       header("Location:login.php?m=$msg"); //msg="Invalid Login"
   }
```

and one more thing; you are using two index for email data  *$_SESSION['**email1**']* and  *$_SESSION['**email**']*. first one (email1) is wrong.

Comment: yaah it waz email1 then I changed it to "email".

Comment: yaah it waz email1 then I changed it to "email". I deleted all the white spaces and also ?> still it wont work.